# find a string in an array with splited variable letters

Tags: php, arrays, string

```
$string = 'Ma';

$arr1 = str_split($string);

foreach($arr1 as $a)
{
    echo $a."<br>";
}

$os = array("Mac", "NT", "Irix", "Linux", "apple");
```

Here I have some strings in `$string` variable. In this line `echo $a."<br>";` it returns this result

```
M
a
```

it splits the string. Now I want to find the words (`array("Mac", "NT", "Irix", "Linux", "apple");`) with these splited string (M  a). For example, My string is Ma, First I want to find the string in an array which string starting with `M` and next I want to find another string in an array which string with `a`. Then I want to echo those both strings. Results should be `Mac apple`. How do I get it?

Comment: `foreach($arr as $item) { if (substr($item, 0, 1) == 'M') { found_it(); }}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just loop the array and compare the first letter of the strings.

```
$string = 'Ma';
$arr1 = str_split($string);
$os = array("Mac", "NT", "Irix", "Linux", "apple");

foreach($arr1 as $a)
{
    foreach ($os as $o)
    {
       if ($o[0] === $a) 
           echo $o, "<br/>"; // Mac<br/>apple<br/>
    }
}
```

Or, with a different approach:

```
$string = 'Ma';
$arr1 = str_split($string);
$os = array("Mac", "NT", "Irix", "Linux", "apple");

foreach ($os as $o)
    if(in_array($o[0], $arr1))
       echo $o, "<br/>";
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
$string = 'Ma';
$oses = array("Mac", "NT", "Irix", "Linux", "apple");

foreach (str_split($string) as $first_letter) {
    $fl_array = preg_grep("/^".$first_letter."/", $oses);

    var_dump($fl_array);
}
```

Output:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(3) "Mac"
}
array(1) {
  [4]=>
  string(5) "apple"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php


    $arr=array("Mac",'apple',"linux");

      foreach($arr as $v){

          if(preg_match("/^M/",$v)){

           echo $v."\n";
      }

       if(preg_match("/^a/",$v)){

           echo $v;
       }
}
?>
```